# HTML/CSS Animation on pushed down content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap row that is hidden by default. After a click on a specific button the jQuery `toggle()` is called to toggle the display of this row.

Is there a way to animate that button to move down? The button is positioned below the row that is toggled to show/hide.

The `#advancetoggle` button should move down with animation, if I use CSS's `transition: transform(0,100px)` the button starts to move down but it jumps due to the row above that gets the display:block and it pushes the button far way down.

Thanks :)

```js
$("#advancetoggle").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('#advanced-search').toggleClass('show hide');
  if ($('#adv-icon').hasClass('icon-arrowdown')){
    $('#adv-icon').removeClass('icon-arrowdown');
    $('#adv-icon').addClass('icon-arrowup');
  } else {
    $('#adv-icon').removeClass('icon-arrowup');
    $('#adv-icon').addClass('icon-arrowdown');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form id="advanced-search">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="typeselect">Type</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="typeselect">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="basedin">Based in</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="basedin">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="town">Town</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="town">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn btn-red">
        RESET FILTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="advanced col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="glyphdown" id="advancetoggle"><i class="icon-arrowdown" id="adv-icon"></i></a> <span class="advanced-text"> Advanced Search</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, please please share the jsfiddle link and also add the css in it. That will explain your problem very well.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle with styles to replicate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues in your code:

1. `transition: transform(0,100px)` should be `transform: translate(0,100px)`.
2. To get the transition you need to add `transition:all .3s ease` (for example).
3. Insert the span `.advanced-text` into the link `#advancetoggle`

```js
$("#advancetoggle").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).css('transform', 'translate(0,100px)');
  console.log($(this));
  $('#advanced-search').toggleClass('show hide');
  if ($('#adv-icon').hasClass('icon-arrowdown')){
    $('#adv-icon').removeClass('icon-arrowdown');
    $('#adv-icon').addClass('icon-arrowup');
  } else {
    $('#adv-icon').removeClass('icon-arrowup');
    $('#adv-icon').addClass('icon-arrowdown');
  }
});
```

```css
#advancetoggle {
  display:inline-block;  
  transition:all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <form id="advanced-search">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="typeselect">Type</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="typeselect">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="basedin">Based in</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="basedin">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="town">Town</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="town">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn btn-red">
        RESET FILTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="advanced col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="glyphdown" id="advancetoggle">
      <i class="icon-arrowdown" id="adv-icon"></i>
      <span class="advanced-text">Advanced Search</span>
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think this is what  you want.hope this will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
 .myrow{
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
 }

 .myrowtwo{
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
 }

 .buttonone , .buttontwo{
  margin:10px;
 }
</style>
<body>

<div class="btn btn-default buttonone">Press me !</div>
<div class="row myrow">
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="basedin">Based in</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="basedin">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="town">Town</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="town">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="btn btn-primary buttontwo">Press me now!</div>
<div class="row myrowtwo">
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="basedin">Based in</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="basedin">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="town">Town</label>
      <div class="custom-select fa-caret-down">
        <select class="form-control" id="town">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".buttonone").click(function(){
        $(".myrow").toggle();
       });

       $(".buttontwo").click(function(){
        $(".myrowtwo").toggle();
       });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used online bootstrap and jquery.good luck.